# Monitoring for files using chokidar

Tags: node.js

I am trying to setup a monitoring piece in my app, I am using chokidar to do so.
I want the app to be awake all the time monitoring the directory for new file, once it see any new file it should move it a directory. Now i have used batch file to move the files (because with the fs.rename) I keep getting errbusy.

Here is my code, the problem is that I dont see the app being awake, It starts and close. I dont see its waiting to check on files. What am i doing wrong here

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function movefile() { exec('movetostage.bat', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err)
    {
  console.log(err);
  return ;
    }
  console.log(stdout);

});
}


function monitordir(){
    var watcher = chokidar.watch(DATA_PATH, {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});
watcher
  .on('add', function(event,path) {
      if(event){
      console.log(event,path);
    movefile();
    main();
  }
  })
}
```

I have added watcher.on('add'), I am guessing that is to check if there is any new files, but the important part here is that the app doesnt keep monitoring it exists

Comment: Is that your whole app? Because if it is, you're not calling `monitordir`

Comment: if (module.parent == undefined){
 
 monitordir();
 //main();
 
}